# SharePoint Online Search Results Edit Links (Edit ERROR)

Tags: sharepoint-online, search-results

I'm currently trying to find the "Edit Links" button at the top of the search results page, much like it is on the search page or any other pages in my site.

[image: Edit Links Buttion]

Is it possible to get it on the search results page?

---

(Edit) I realized it was the CSS that was the issue, I went into sharepoint designer and modified the ASPX file where it had:

```
#s4-titlerow
{ 
    display: none !important; 
}
```

I removed it and now I get this error any time I try to search:

> **Sorry, something went wrong**
>
> The base type
>   'Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Internal.UI.SearchResultsLayoutPage'
>   is not allowed for this page. The type
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Internal.UI.SearchResultsLayoutPage,
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c could not be found or it is not
>   registered as safe. TECHNICAL DETAILS
>
> Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation.
>
> Correlation ID: d6e6119d-605b-2000-0a31-5b24d35d076c

I changed it back to what it was and saved, but the error still exists.

Comment: I see it on my search results in one of my site collections. This leads me to believe you don't have the proper permissions. What permissions do you have at the root of your site collection?

Comment: I have admin permissions and I realized that the CSS had it hidden. I went into Sharepoint designer and modified the CSS so that it would show, instead of being marked as display: none !important; Now I am getting a major error after editing

Answer (score 2):

Had to reset the site definition in order to fix my issue.

Comment: I had the same problem and resetting worked for me. But i need to remove the display: none from the title row. Any way you could do this?

Answer (score 0):

I just went thru several hours of MS Support to fix this issue. I too had added css to a search page and received the same error as above. The fix was the following:

1) Open the site collection in SharePoint Designer

2) Click on ‘Page Layouts’ in the left navigation pane

3) Right click on ‘searchresults.aspx’ page and click on ‘Reset to Site Definition’

Hope this helps someone!